# Generating human readable filenames in Apache Airflow vía {{ run_id }} in a templated bash command

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

My DAG dumps some data from a database and stores it in a local file.

Other tasks (within the same DagRun) will read it, process it, etc.

To save locally, I need to create a filename based on the dag, the task that created it and the dag run:

```
{{ dag.dag_id }}_{{ task.task_id }}_{{ run_id }}.csv
```

and I get something like that:

```
my_dag_my_task_manual__2019-01-11T11:56:00.902937+00:00.csv
```

How could I get the filename more human readable? I mean, something like this:

```
my_dag_my_task_manual__2019_01_11_11_56_00_902937_00_00.csv
```

This is the templated bash command where the task (BashOperator) compose the filename:

```
bash_command = \
        """
        comm -2 -3 {source_a_filepath} {source_b_filepath} > {TMP_PATH}/{{{{ dag.dag_id }}}}_{{{{ task.task_id }}}}_{{{{ run_id }}}}.csv;
        echo '{{{{ dag.dag_id }}}}_{{{{ task.task_id }}}}_{{{{ run_id }}}}'
        """.format(
            source_a_filepath=source_a_filepath,
            source_b_filepath=source_b_filepath,
            TMP_PATH=TMP_PATH)
```

Comment: Can you do something like `run_id_readable = f'{run_id:%Y%m%d}'` and then call `echo '{{{{ dag.dag_id }}}}_{{{{ task.task_id }}}}_{{{{ run_id_readable }}}}'`?

Comment: I'm afraid that run_id is `<class 'str'>` not a `datetime`.

Comment: I guess you could convert it to datetime (`strftime`) and then back to a string in that case?

Comment: Anyway, if you embrace something between `{{{{ }}}}` (`{{ }}` after fstring format) it should be a a macro (or other symbol in the jinja template context)

Comment: in the case of the BashOperator, you could inject run_id_readable vía `params={'run_id_readable':'...'"`

Comment: but I'm afraid, at param injection time, run_id is still not available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail with the message `name 'run_id' is not defined` because at param injection time, `run_id` is still not available:

```
bash_command = \
    """
    echo '{{ params.run_id_readable }}';
    """

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="t1",
    bash_command=bash_command,
    params={"run_id_readable": run_id.split('.')[0].replace('T', '_').replace('-', '').replace(':', '')},
    dag=dag,
)
```

This will fail again, because `kwargs` is also not available:

```
bash_command = \
    """
    echo '{{ params.run_id_readable }}';
    """

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="t1",
    bash_command=bash_command,
    params={"run_id_readable": kwargs.get('run_id').split('.')[0].replace('T', '_').replace('-', '').replace(':', '')},

    dag=dag,
)
```

This would be the correct way, as `run_id` symbol will be available at jinja template render time:

```
bash_command = \
    """
    echo '{{ run_id.split('.')[0].replace('T', '_').replace('-', '').replace(':', '') }}';
    """

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="t1",
    bash_command=bash_command,
    dag=dag,
)
```

With `PythonOperator` you could take advantage of that `kwargs` dict is available at `callable_function` execution time:

```
def python_callable(**kwargs):
    """ """
    dag_id = kwargs.get('dag').dag_id
    task_id = kwargs.get('task').task_id
    run_id = kwargs.get('run_id', '-.:').split('.')[0].replace('T', '_').replace('-', '').replace(':', '')
    print("{}_{}_{}".format(dag_id, task_id, run_id))

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="t2",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=python_callable,
    dag=dag)
```